# R - get a vector that tells me if a value of another vector is the first appearence or not

Tags: sql, r

I have a data frame of sales with three columns: the code of the customer, the month the customer bought that item, and the year.

A customer can buy something in september and then in december make another purchase, so appear two times. But I'm interested in knowing the absolutely new customoers by month and year.

So I have thought in make an iteration and some checks and use the %in% function and build a boolean vector that tells me if a customer is new or not and then count by month and year with SQL using this new vector.

But I'm wondering if there's a specific function or a better way to do that.

This is an example of the data I would like to have:

```
     date   cust  month new_customer
1   14975      25   1    TRUE
2   14976      30   1    TRUE
3   14977      22   1    TRUE
4   14978       4   1    TRUE
5   14979      25   1    FALSE
6   14980      11   1    TRUE
7   14981      17   1    TRUE
8   14982      17   1    FALSE
9   14983      18   1    TRUE
10  14984       7   1    TRUE
11  14985      24   1    TRUE
12  14986      22   1    FALSE
```

So put it more simple: the data frame is sorted by date, and I'm interested in a vector (new_customer) that tells me if the customer purchased something for the first time or not. For example customer 25 bought something the first day, and then four days later bought something again, so is not a new customer. The same can be seen with customer 17 and 22.

Comment: If one customer visit at Dec 2020 and then Dec 2021. Is this customer new customers by month and year ?

Comment: Please add some example data to make this a reproducible example.

Comment: if one customer visit dec 2020 fot the first time, it will be a new customer, if appears again in dec 2021 will not be a new customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create dummy data my self with `id`, `month` of numeric format, and `year`

```
dat <-data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,3,4,5,1,2,2),
  month = c(1,6,7,8,2,3,4,8,11,1,10,9,1,12,2),
  year = c(2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021)
)

   id month year
1   1     1 2019
2   2     6 2019
3   3     7 2019
4   4     8 2019
5   5     2 2019
6   6     3 2020
7   7     4 2020
8   8     8 2020
9   1    11 2020
10  3     1 2020
11  4    10 2021
12  5     9 2021
13  1     1 2021
14  2    12 2021
15  2     2 2021
```

Then, group by `id` and `arrange` by `year` and `month` (order is meaningful). Then use `filter` and `row_number()`.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(year, month) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)

     id month  year
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1  2019
2     5     2  2019
3     2     6  2019
4     3     7  2019
5     4     8  2019
6     6     3  2020
7     7     4  2020
8     8     8  2020
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Code**

You can change in your code according to this logic:-

1. **Create Table**:-

`CREATE TABLE PURCHASE(Posting_Date DATE,Customer_Id INT,Customer_Name VARCHAR(15));`

2. **Insert Data Into Table**

   ```
    Posting_Date    Customer_Id Customer_Name
    2018-01-01  C_01    Jack
    2018-02-01  C_01    Jack
    2018-03-01  C_01    Jack
    2018-04-01  C_02    James
    2019-04-01  C_01    Jack
    2019-05-01  C_01    Jack
    2019-05-01  C_03    Gill
    2020-01-01  C_02    James
    2020-01-01  C_04    Jones
   ```

**Code**

```
WITH Date_CTE (PostingDate,CustomerID,FirstYear) 
    AS
    (  
        SELECT MIN(Posting_Date) as [Date],
               Customer_Id,
               YEAR(MIN(Posting_Date)) as [F_Purchase_Year]
            FROM PURCHASE
            GROUP BY Customer_Id 
    )  
    
    SELECT T.[ActualYear],(CASE WHEN T.[Customer Status] = 'new' THEN COUNT(T.[Customer Status]) END) AS [New Customer]
    FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(T2.Posting_Date) AS [ActualYear],
            T2.Customer_Id,
            (CASE WHEN T1.FirstYear = YEAR(T2.Posting_Date) THEN 'new' ELSE 'old' END) AS [Customer Status]
    FROM Date_CTE AS T1
    left outer join PURCHASE AS T2 ON T1.CustomerID = T2.Customer_Id
    ) AS T
    GROUP BY T.[ActualYear],T.[Customer Status]
```

**Final Result**

```
ActualYear  New Customer
2018    2
2019    1
2020    1
2019    NULL
2020    NULL
```